# Expose AWS EKS Service Through Cloudfront on Top of AWS ALB Ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to expose our Kubernetes service through alb and CloudFront.

We have created distribution and added load balancer origin with X-Custom-Header: cloudfront-header

In the load balancer, we have manually created a rule
HTTP Header X-Custom-Header is cloudfront-header: Forward to kubernetes-service-target-group : 1 (100%)

The above solution seems to be working and exposing our Kubernetes service through CloudFront on top of ALB but we want to make this configuration through ingress.yaml file because for any configuration change the old rules get removed which are manually added.

[cloudfront configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55tD9.png)
[AWS ALB configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvKqI.png)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-1:xxxx:certificate/daxxx-xxx-43c8-ada-cb5c97a1366b
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: domain-web
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "443"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
  finalizers:
  - group.ingress.k8s.aws/domain-web
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: domain-web
    app.kubernetes.io/name: domain-web
  name: domain-web
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
  - host: market.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: marketing
            port:
              number: 3000
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific              
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - market.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your CloudFront distribution with the following configuration:

#### Configure the `Origin` pointing to your AWS ALB:

- Set `Origin domain` to your `ELB (AWS ALB)` DNS
- HTTPS only if you want it as TLS termination

[image: CloudFront - Origin]

#### Set your `Default(*)` behavior pointing to your `Origin`:

- Select your `Origin` pointing to your `ELB (AWS ALB)`
- Redirect HTTP to HTTPS since we only accepted `HTTPS` in the `Origin`

[image: CloudFront - Behavior]

#### Settings - Configure Domain and Certs:

- Add the domain you want to use (e.g. `market.domain.com`)
- Add the Certs from AWS Certificate Manager for `market.domain.com` or `*.domain.com`

**Note**: It's fine if you haven't define the subdomain domain yet in `Route 53`, but it will help defining it here before we do the `Route 53` step. You can always come back and edit the `Settings` to add the domain.

[image: CloudFront - Settings]

#### Add `Route 53` record for your sub domain

- Go to `Route 53` and `Hosted zones`
- Go to your domain `domain.com`
- Click on `Create record`
- Enter your subdomain on `Record name` (e.g. `market`).
- Enable `Alias` toggle
- In `Route traffic to` select `Alias to CloudFront distribution`
- In `Choose distribution` select the distribution created for `market.domain.com`

[image: Route 53 - Add A record to your domain]

#### Verification

After this is setup you should be able to do a request to your `Service` in your Kubernetes cluster through `market.domain.com`.

Assuming you have a `/healthcheck` route:

**Example:**

```bash
curl https://market.domain.com/healthcheck
```

This works because the request will come from `market.domain.com` which will have the following `Header`: `Host: market.domain.com`

**Explaination:**

- `AWS ALB` routes your request to your `Ingress` object (`domain-web` in this case) which uses the `Host` header to resolve to which `Service` in your cluster it has to deliver the request.
- That will be equivalent to doing the following request:

```bash
curl -H "Host: market.domain.com" k8s-sddsdfsds.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/healthcheck
```